# Unhandled promise rejection while sending email using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I'm using this script for sending email:

```
var mailer = require('nodemailer');

var smtpTransport = mailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'user',
        pass: 'pass'
    }
});

 smtpTransport.sendMail({       
        sender: 'user',
        to: 'user',
        subject: 'Attachment!',
        body: 'mail content...',
        attachments: [{   
        filename: 'text3.txt',
        path: 'pat/to/file.txt' 
    }]
    }), function(err, success) {
        if (err) {
        }

    }
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 9): Error: connect
>   ETIMEDOUT

What's wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unhandled Promise rejection means that there is some Promise function that doesn't have a *.catch*. Nodemailer's .sendMail function is a Promise function so you can either have a callback or use it like a Promise.

In your code your fuction(err, sucess) is outside of your .sendMail function. Here is how you could correct it:

```
 smtpTransport.sendMail({       
    sender: 'user',
    to: 'user',
    subject: 'Attachment!',
    body: 'mail content...',
    attachments: [{   
    filename: 'text3.txt',
    path: 'pat/to/file.txt' 
}]
},(err, success) => {
    if (err) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, firstly what is wrong is you have a ETIMEDOUT error coming from your email call. Are you sure you have all the parameters correct?

Secondly use Promises, rather than callback style, and catch the rejection. Like this,

```
smtpTransport
  .sendMail(...)
  .then(success => console.log('success: ', success))
  .catch(error => console.log('error: ', error))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is a rejection from GMail, Try Login in to: [https//www.google.com/setti
ngs/security/lesssecureapps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) and TURN ON "*Access for less secure apps*". 
Or use OAuth.